# how to git rid of the white space on my webpage I'm working with handlebars.js?

Tags: css, handlebars.js

As shown in the screen shot I can not remove the white space at the bottom. I tried some solutions but they are not working. Please let me know if there will be any solution for this problem.

[image: Browser Screenshot 1]

[image: Browser Screenshot 2]

Comment: PLease take the [tour] and read the [help] for more information on what is expected in a StackOverflow question. Where is your code? Please provide a [MCVE] that illustrates the problem. "I have tried some solutions" - what was the closest one of those? "They are not working" - be more specific, how are they not working?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.